# Input with spacing will show error

Tags: java

I have a problem with this java script if I enter the input with spacing cant work. without spacing no problem. I have try a lot of edit but still cannot solve this problem, I wrote getloan will show the result, but if I write 
get loan with spacing will show error. what I should add on to solve this?

```
Scanner  read = new Scanner(System.in);
{
    System.out.println("Enter the phone number: ");
    String  telLetter = read.next();
    telLetter = telLetter.toUpperCase();
    String  telNumber = " ";
    int count = 0;
    int  i = 0;
    while (count <7)
    {
        switch (telLetter.charAt(i))
        {
        case 'A':case 'B':case 'C':
            telNumber += "2";
            count++;
            break;
        case 'D':case 'E':case 'F':
            telNumber += "3";
            count++;
            break;
        case 'G':case 'H':case 'I':
            telNumber += "4";
            count++;
            break;
        case 'J':case 'K':case 'L':
            telNumber += "5";
            count++;
            break;
        case 'M':case 'N':case 'O':
            telNumber += "6";
            count++;
            break;
        case 'P':case 'R':case 'Q':case 'S':
            telNumber += "7";
            count++;
            break;
        case 'T':case 'U':case 'V':
            telNumber += "8";
            count++;
            break;
        case 'W':case 'X':case 'Y':case 'Z':
            telNumber += "9";
            count++;
            break;
        }
        if (count == 3)
            telNumber += "-";
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(telNumber);
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Are you sure this is Javascript ? Seems like Java to me.

Comment: If you don't share the code, there's no way for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry! here to go!!

Comment: @KobyDouek "java script" mind the space :)

Comment: Read the javadoc of Scanner, and of its next() method. What does it do? That will give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because `Scanner.next()` will give you `get` and not `get loan` and you have hardcoded your loop to process 7 valid letters. Scanner by default delimits on whitespace.

Comment: @KhengHuatLim once again, that information is available in the Scanner javadoc. Which of the methods listed here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html could possibly return the next line?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` if you want to delimit on the new line.

Comment: Thank you so much!! this helps me a lot!!! but my output with whitespace will have 438--5626 double --

Comment: Use trim() to remove the white-spaces, then replace `--` with `-` using `replace()`